# Flex Slider 2 - Navigation buttons not showing

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have a site using the Flex Slider 2 component. It is working fine but the navigation buttons are not showing. When I move the mouse over the area where the buttons are supposed to be, the cursor behaves as if they actually were there. I can slide the images by clicking on the point where the buttons are supposed to be. Please see my code below. Any help on this is highly appreciated

```
jQuery.noConflict($);


$(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
      slideshowSpeed: 10000,
      controlNav: true,
      directionNav: true
   });
 });
```

Comment: Did you include the CSS of FlexSlider ? And the images of these links? Is your CSS not blocking it, like a z-index on every anchors ? It would be nice to have a live page or a JSFiddle to help you !

Comment: Please see www.cybersearchme.no for the live page. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.Found the problem. They have replaced graphic .png with a font file. Soooo, copy the font directory included in the download onto your server. Remap path in CSS. I had to add '/'  to src:url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot'); before 'fonts...' So this: src:url('/fonts/flexslider-icon.eot'); Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

in flexslider.css line 55 you have opacity set to 0 for these buttons and background set to non-existing image

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess this was a quite obvious mistake. I appreciate your help. Now it works fine.